# How to export an animation that uses a curve modifier?

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, bezier-curves, instances

This is my animation of a shotgun ammo belt. It uses a set of placeholder Plane meshes along a Bezier curve that instance my shell model. By moving the planes across the z axis, the shells feed into the gun. However, this doesn't work in the exported file because the Curve modifier is not applied. Applying the modifier causes the entire belt to move back and forth instead of each shell following the curve. Does anyone have a solution to this that would allow me to export the animation into a game engine?

[image: desired effect]
[image: after curve is applied]

my gorgeous ms paint illustrations might explain this issue, but I'll be glad to offer more information if it would help :p

Comment: this solution https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/231715/131687 work perfectly, for the curve direction. but in my case, the array modifier that already applied is not showing. it only show 1 part of my object following the curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really an expert, but I had this problem too. How I solved it was:

- Exporting the curve as .abc file with 'Selected Objects Only' box checked.
- Import this same file again. All keyframes will disappear while the animation is still shown correctly.
- Additionally you might have to export as .mdd file (you should check this option in the preferences menu first).

Hope this helps, and if there's a better way, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

If you export as Alembic to Unity, you need to install Alembic package to add support for your file.

Also you need to animate Time parameter in Alembic Stream Player component.