# NURBS Curve Animating Start/End Mapping For Unity

Tags: animation, unity, path

I'm trying hard to export this animation to Unity, but everything I have tried has failed and everything I google is about how to move an object on the path.

[image]

I have tried exporting to Alembic(AKA THIS LINK [How to export an animation that uses a curve modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231709/how-to-export-an-animation-that-uses-a-curve-modifier) ) . Its making keyframes for each frame, but I need it as a mesh to use it in Unity.

although I explained clearly this is not moving an object or bending it along a curve for some reason my question is marked as duplicate!!!
I dont know how tf I can make this more clear just look at the picture in the link and my gif if you have trouble understanding this.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: i didnt know i had to say this but theres literally 0 material or textures in this